# Single Sign on integration based authentication in RefineryCMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, refinerycms

Is it possible to integrate Single Sign on based authentication in RefineryCMS? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As version 3.0 or RefineryCMS has extracted authentication system from core, you should be able to implement any custom authentication system, even SSO. You can check https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-authentication-devise as a start example.

Comment: And if you are looking for a SAML integration:
https://github.com/ivanoblomov/omniauth-saml#devise-integration

Comment: You probably DONT want  to *use* authentication-devise, as it adds a password-based authentication system, but you may want to look at it for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Philip Arndt and i have created a Solidus (https://solidus.io/) and Refinery CMS (http://refinerycms.com/) single authentication with Devise :

https://github.com/refinerycms-contrib/solidus-refinery-authentication

It should help you to create your own authentication with Devise.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented an SSO solution.  In my case I could take advantage of Spnego being in the request stack, so it added a header to the request with the authenticated user id.

Refinery uses devise, which ultimately uses zilch-authentication. In my case, I specialized the zilch user and zilch authentication adapter classes to read this header.

Sorry in this case I am not allowed to share my code with you, but it was dead easy, once I knew about zilch.  I hope that's enough of a clue